# How to print a part of a filename using Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to print a part of filename in Tcl like ....
Suppose I have a `set string "/home/Documents/galaxy/my_folder"` and instead of `puts $string` to get the whole string, I want to print `my_folder` only.
How can I do so ? please suggest if there is any appropriate Tcl command.

Comment: For the future, please consider the fact that here you fell victim of the "XY Problem syndrome" -- asking for help with your *solution* rather than describing the original problem (more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)). This case was simple enough for everyone to understand, but such approach might bite you later with more complicated problems ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the last component from a path, you would use [`file tail`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M38):

```
file tail $string
```

And if you happen to want it using `puts`:

```
puts [file tail $string]
```